# ZSH prompt starts with a percent sign on Hyper terminal

Tags: terminal, configuration, customization, zsh, hyper

I'm using Hyper as my terminal on Linux Mint 19.2 and I've just installed ZSH with Oh My ZSH. when I open Hyper, a percentage sign appears before the prompt.

[image: Here's a picture of the prompt's startup]

Comment: Provide your ZSH configuration files.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167582/5132 .

Answer (score 1):

That reverse-video `%` indicates an output that did not end with a newline:

```sh
/home/ekalin $ echo 'Hello, World'
Hello, World
/home/ekalin $ echo -n 'Hello, World'
Hello, World%
/home/ekalin $
```

So there must be something that's outputting a line without a newline. If it happens in every prompt, it should be in your prompt definition; if it happens only on session startup, it should be something from `~/.zshrc` (or in a file sourced from there).